# Javascript. How to extract URI encoded email from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

```
var string = 'https://opt.portal.co.uk/index/stepregistration/Username/test%40test.es/nextstep/1/lang/es?kmi=K54Nv1RdlV71hhiLEdPg0UZ0%3D&_ga=1.217245974.18890806.1485212';
```

Email is encoded like so **test%40test.es**

What is the way to get this email address with JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the following way :

- use [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to decode the URI
- use a `regex` to extract the email address

```js
var string = 'https://opt.portal.co.uk/index/stepregistration/Username/test%40test.es/nextstep/1/lang/es?kmi=K54Nv1RdlV71hhiLEdPg0UZ0%3D&_ga=1.217245974.18890806.1485212';
var email = decodeURIComponent(string).match(/\w+@\w+\.\w+/g)[0];
console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decodeURIComponent(string)
```

example from w3c:

```
var uri = "https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
var res = uri_enc + "<br>" + uri_dec;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

In your example you'll want to extract the username from the url. Querystring or Hash key/value pairs might be easier to deal with but you can use a regular expression or split the url by '/' and loop the result to find the element after the 'Username' element.